# En mi aplicación desarrollada con JAVA + SpringBoot quiero utilizar datos de una tabla para crear nuevos registros en otra tabla referenciada con FK

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

soy nuevo usando SpringBoot-JPA y no se como resolver un caso de uso de mi pagina.
Quiero insertar un registro de nueva Venta (solamente la parte cabecera) insertando el ID de  Cliente que ya EXISTE en mi BD, o sea no tendría que generar un nuevo cliente.
Como lo planteo no me funciona, me devuelve un error de JavaNullPointer en la parte del constructor que indico mas abajo. Estoy seguro que algo en mi modelo no esta bien pero no logro identificarlo.
Como podría pasar a mi nueva Venta un ID_CLIENTE ya existente en mi BD?

**Clase Cliente:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente", catalog = "winsun")
public class Cliente {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id_cliente;
    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @Column
    private String apellido;
    @Column
    private String descripcion;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private Set<Ventas> venta = new HashSet<>();

public Cliente(String nombre, String apellido, String descripcion) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;

}
```

getters/setters...

**Clase Ventas (cabecera):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ventas", catalog = "winsun")
public class Ventas {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private int id_venta;

@Column
private Date fecha;
@Column
private String descripcion;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="id_cliente", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Cliente client;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "venta", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<VentasDetalle> ventasDetalle;
```

getters/setters...

**CONSTRUCTOR Ventas (cabecera)...**

```
public Ventas(int id_cli,Date fecha, String descripcion) {
    this.client.setId_cliente(id_cli); **// ACA ME FALLA CON EL JAVANULLPOINTER**
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
```

***Invocación al constructor de Ventas:***

```
try{
Ventas vta = new Ventas(6,fechaActual,"Descripcion venta");
   vta.agregarDetalle(vtadetail);
   System.out.println("vta = " + vta.toString());
   repoVentas.save(vta);

}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());

}
}
```

Ojala que me puedan dar una mano!! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el objeto `Cliente client` es nulo por eso no puedes asignarle valores, de igual forma la logical en JPA es que primero busques al cliente por su id y cuando tengas el objeto cliente lo pases al constructor de ventas `new Ventas(objetoCliente,fechaActual,"Descripcion venta");`.

Comment: Gracias @RobertoEMoran! Pude solucionar el problema con tu ayuda. No tenia en claro que la logica JPA para esos casos debo si o si buscar o definir en mi código los datos del objeto a reutilizar.